# Atom: don't switch tab to latest

Tags: atom-editor

Until now when I was switching tabs on atom with `ctrl-tab` or `ctrl-shift-tab`, it used to go to the tab on the right or left. Now it switches to last visited and first visited. Any idea how to reset this to left/right ?

I checked the atom settings but couldn't find anything related to tab-switching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They [changed it](https://discuss.atom.io/t/disable-most-recently-used-tab-switching/27825) in 1.7.0 (that feature was requested a lot).

You can [edit your keybindings to set it back](http://blog.atom.io/2016/04/12/atom-1-7-and-1-8-beta.html).
In 'Edit' -> 'Keymap...' put

```
'body':
  'ctrl-tab ^ctrl': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-tab': 'pane:show-next-item'
  'ctrl-shift-tab ^ctrl': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-shift-tab': 'pane:show-previous-item'
```

Comment: Thanks ! In OS X it's in 'Atom' -> 'Keymap'